# Setting GOOS with go run

Tags: go

I'm currently developing a service that can be built as windows service or run as OSX/linux executable.

I'm using build tags on windows files, including the one with a main method

```
// +build windows
```

And on the other file containing a main method

```
// +build !windows
```

When I execute `go run *.go` on the mac side, I get the following error

```
mainDOS.go:10:2: no buildable Go source files in /Users/michaelbrandenburg/Documents/git-repo/goCode/src/golang.org/x/sys/windows/svc
windowsService.go:15:2: no buildable Go source files in /Users/michaelbrandenburg/Documents/git-repo/goCode/src/golang.org/x/sys/windows/svc/debug
install.go:14:2: no buildable Go source files in /Users/michaelbrandenburg/Documents/git-repo/goCode/src/golang.org/x/sys/windows/svc/eventlog
install.go:15:2: no buildable Go source files in /Users/michaelbrandenburg/Documents/git-repo/goCode/src/golang.org/x/sys/windows/svc/mgr
```

Is there a way to run `go run` and target the architecture I want to run? I can build the executables with no problem.

Comment: There's no point in setting GOOS with `go run`, because `go run` is meant to execute immediately on the host OS.

Comment: Or maybe you're confused about "build constraints"? `go run` doesn't follow build constraints, because you're already explicitly listing the files to build as arguments. You shouldn't be using `go run` for more than simple testing, and you have `go install` and `go build` for working with complete packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GOOS=darwin go run *.go` will set the env for Mac OSX. Though, like JimB said, there isn't much of a point. Doing `GOOS=darwin go build *.go` is a good way to cross compile though

Comment: Using this for building a docker image and it works great. I was getting: exec user process caused "exec format error" when trying to run my built docker image. The environments didn't match, so this seemed to work for building the Golang binary for a linux environment. Thanks